# java.lang.NullPointerException in uploading Large Files with Struts

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

i have problem in uploading larger file in struts
while uploading file it reaches form bean and action is coming to My Action file but when i read FormFile type from DynaAction Form object it =s throwing null pointer Exception

```html
<html:form action="/Machmandateupld" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<tr class="frm_section_reven">
                <td width="25%" class="frm_section_rod1"><%--changed by Q1Y 26-08-2017--%> 
                    <span id="txtMyUpldFileLabel" class="panbdytblcolbeancls">
                        <bean:message key="LBL00396"/>
                    </span> 
                </td>       
                <td class="tdinputboxclass">
                        <html:file property="txtMyUpldFile" size ="75" 
                               styleClass="blurfield"
                               onkeypress="keyPressEvents(event)" 
                               onfocus="displayFieldMsg(event)"
                               onkeydown="keyDownEvents(event)"
                               >
                        </html:file>
                        <b class="manfield"><bean:message key="LBL03968"/>
                        </b>    
                </td>               
            </tr>
```

my Action.java

```js
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        DynaActionForm dynaForm     = (DynaActionForm)form;
        
        DTObject clientData   = new DTObject();
        DTObject resultDTO    = new DTObject(); 
        FormFile formFile     = (FormFile)dynaForm.get("txtMyUpldFile");
        ResourceBundle labels=null;
        labels=ResourceBundle.getBundle("cmsutility.resources.ApplicationResources_"+request.getSession().getAttribute("SELECTEDLANG"));
        Laserlog.info("dynaForm txtMyUpldFile" +dynaForm.get("txtMyUpldFile"));
        Laserlog.info("formFile.getFileSize():" +formFile.getFileSize());
        Laserlog.info("formFile.getFileName():" +formFile.getFileName());       
        fileName              = formFile.getFileName();
        fileName              = fileName.toUpperCase();
        FormatFile            = (String)dynaForm.get("txtFmtCode");
        calcurrbusDate        = (String)dynaForm.get("hubCBD");
        entityCode            = (String)dynaForm.get("entityCode");
        UserID                = (String)dynaForm.get("UserID");
        chkIQAReq             = (String)dynaForm.get("chkIQAReq");

        clientData.setValue("CBOUPLDTYPE","HB");
        clientData.setValue("TXTCHANNELREFNO",refid);
        clientData.setValue("ENTITYCODE",entityCode);
        clientData.setValue("TXTCURDATE",calcurrbusDate);
        clientData.setValue("TXTCHANNELUSERID",UserID);//
        clientData.setValue("TXTFILENAME",fileName); //  File name without path
        clientData.setValue("TXTACTFILE",fileName);
        clientData.setValue("TXTFMTCODE",FormatFile);
        clientData.setValue("IQAREQ",chkIQAReq);
        clientData.setValue("TXTCHANNELID","CNR");
        clientData.setValue("EOrU","U");
    }
```

My struts-config.xml

```html
<form-bean name="Machmandateupld" type="org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm">
    <form-property name="txtMyUpldFile" type="org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile"/>
    <form-property name="txtEffDate" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <form-property name="entityCode" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <form-property name="userAccessRights" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <form-property name="UserID" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <form-property name="txtCustCode" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <form-property name="userId" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <form-property name="hubCBD" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <form-property name="txtFmtCode" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <form-property name="txtProdCode" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <form-property name="chkIQAReq" type="java.lang.String"/>
    </form-bean>
    
    <action name="Machmandateupld" path="/Machmandateupld"
   scope="request" type="com.lsi.cms.actions.MachmandateupldAction">
   <forward name="success" path="/machmandateupld.jsp"/>
   <forward name="failure" path="/machmandateupld.jsp"/>
  </action>
```

I am getting below java.lang.NullPointerException

```html
[6/29/20 18:45:22:483 IST] 0000015b PropertyMessa I org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init> Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.taglib.html.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
[6/29/20 18:45:24:610 IST] 0000015b ServletWrappe I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [CollectionsBO] [/cmsweb] [HelpServlet]: Initialization successful.
[6/29/20 18:45:27:489 IST] 00000157 SystemOut     O validatetxtfmtcode
[6/29/20 18:45:27:489 IST] 00000157 SystemOut     O else
[6/29/20 18:45:54:074 IST] 00000157 SystemOut     O validatetxtfmtcode
[6/29/20 18:45:54:074 IST] 00000157 SystemOut     O else
[6/29/20 18:45:54:156 IST] 00000158 RequestProces W org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor processException Unhandled Exception thrown: class java.lang.NullPointerException
[6/29/20 18:45:54:157 IST] 00000158 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause action: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:545)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:486)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:964)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3901)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.lsi.cms.actions.MachmandateupldAction.execute(MachmandateupldAction.java:65)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    ... 30 more

[6/29/20 18:45:54:167 IST] 00000158 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /was/IBM/WebSphere/Profiles/cms_cnr/logs/ffdc/cms_cnr_17_6c7f9fd2_20.06.29_18.45.54.1582782008013461971925.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter 82
[6/29/20 18:45:54:169 IST] 00000158 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /was/IBM/WebSphere/Profiles/cms_cnr/logs/ffdc/cms_cnr_17_6c7f9fd2_20.06.29_18.45.54.1684923257927774845432.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters -SE 1078
[6/29/20 18:45:54:169 IST] 00000158 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp **logServletError SRVE0293E: **[Servlet Error]-[action]: java.lang.NullPointerException**
    at com.lsi.cms.actions.MachmandateupldAction.execute(MachmandateupldAction.java:65)**
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:964)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3901)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
```

Note : It not works for File which is uploaded with 10000 records upto 7500 records its working fine

Comment: What's line 65?

Comment: Its refering my action file in which line 65 following is written fileName  = formFile.getFileName();
so i tried adding logs and introduced Laserlog.info("dynaForm txtMyUpldFile" +dynaForm.get("txtMyUpldFile")); then error came at this line itself @DaveNewton Newton

Comment: You're likely running in to a default file upload size limitation. I don't recall how to change it, and it may need to be changed in both server and a Struts file uploader config--searching the web should point to solutions as this was a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly the default max file size is 2MB. Try to add to your `struts-config.xml` (directly as a child of `<struts-config>` tag):

```
<controller maxFileSize="10M" />
```